# Can we have both Physical and Logical replication on the same postgres database for different purposes?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication

I am in a need of having both the Physical and Logical replications of a database for two different purposes.

- Physical replication is to have a DR setup.
- Logical replication is to handle a function requirement.

I believe it will work.

But before trying to configure that, i want to know whether this model is advisable to do or not?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no problem with a single cluster being physical replication primary server and logical replication primary server at the same time.

Comment: I would be good practice to also provide answer HOW?

Comment: @Shahaboddin Well, I answered the question. If OP had asked "how to setup both at the same time?", the answer would be "Just like it says in the documentation". There is nothing special about it.